# Laravel 5.8 - Get values from pluck result

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, pluck

I need help to make this code work. After make a search by a Software, my controller return the locals who have the software installed, and the S.O. who has the same.
For example, this query will return "1 2", because this two images has "Google Chrome".

```
$img_id = Software::where('application', $request->input('application'))->pluck('imagem_id');
```

And than, I need to list all the locals who have this image, after consequence of the search by the Software.

```
$ambientes = Ambiente::where('imagem_id', $img_id)->get();
```

But she only show me the locals who have the imagem_id = 1, even I using a foreach in view:

```
@foreach ($ambientes as $value)
<tr>
   <td>{{ $value->unidade->name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $value->bloco->name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
   <td>{{ $value->imagem_id }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

What I need to do to show every locals who has the image_id = 1 and 2??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, this

```
$img_id = Software::where('application', $request->input('application'))->pluck('imagem_id');
```

should return an array of the two ids like this:

```
[1, 2]
```

If that's the response then you can use [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-wherein):

```
$ambientes = Ambiente::whereIn('imagem_id', $img_id)->get();
```

This will give you a collection of both ambients, and the view stays the same.

Comment: Thanks Dude! Works it WhereIn.

Answer (score 2):

When you're trying to get records that match multiple IDs, you can't use `where()`, you'll need to use `whereIn()`:

```
 $img_id = Software::where('application', $request->input('application'))->pluck('imagem_id');
 // This should return an array/Collection of `imagem_id` values.

 $ambientes = Ambiente::whereIn('imagem_id', $img_id)->get();
```

Now, `$ambientes` should contain `Ambiente` records that match all the `imagem_id` values returned from your initial query.

Comment: Thanks Dude! Works it WhereIn.